# What's Page __EVENTARGUMENT?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, ajax.net

I saw code like this:

```
if (this.Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"] == "Flag")
   //DoSomthing...
```

What does `__EVENTARGUMENT` mean and are there some parameters like it to access?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It can be set by calls to `__doPostBack` in the JavaScript on the page.

[This article](http://aspalliance.com/articleViewer.aspx?aId=895&pId=-1) explains it in a bit more detail.

Comment: In case of dynamic LinkButton `Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"]` is coming as empty string.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486733/how-to-check-whether-postback-caused-by-a-dynamic-link-button

Comment: The second link is broke and redirects to a unrelated website.

Comment: @user2389345436357: Thanks, removed. (Would remove the answer, given that it's almost link-only now, but I can't as it's accepted.)